# extracting string using subtring and instring

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a problem, I used many methods like instring and substring to get the output, but was missing something
Below is the data

V   V1

4   hurdle:longrun:runner:rod:robi

4   hurdle:longrun:runner:rod:robi

3   longrun:jog:rod:robi

2   longrun: sprint :runner:rod:robi

I want output like

V   V1

4   longrun

4   longrun

3   null

2   sprint

actually i want o/p  which is next to “runner” .. Someone please help me

Comment: `I used many methods like instring and substring to get the output`. Please post what  you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
select v, substr(regexp_substr(v1, ':[^:]*:runner'), 1, -7) from TABLE_NAME;
```

(Caveat: I'm afraid I haven't got an Oracle DB to hand, so I haven't tested this myself)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have same table as above , i used your query , but it was not working

Comment: Like, could you be more specific about how it was not working?  My first guess would be that the colons are reserved characters and need escaping.  If that's it, I'd try ':.*?:runner' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution,

```
WITH x AS (SELECT '4 hurdle:longrun:runner:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT '4 hurdle:longrun:runner:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT '3 longrun:jog:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT '2 longrun: sprint :runner:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual )

select 
substr(v_string,1,2)||
substr(v_string,
       instr(v_string,':',1)+1,
       instr(
             substr(v_string,
                    instr(v_string,':',1)+3 ),
             'runner')) from x;
```

OR

```
WITH x AS (SELECT '4 hurdle:longrun:runner:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT '4 hurdle:longrun:runner:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT '3 longrun:jog:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT '2 longrun: sprint :runner:rod:robi' AS v_string FROM dual )

SELECT replace(substr(v_string,1,instr(v_string, ':runner')-1),
               substr(
                      substr(v_string,1,instr(v_string, ':runner')-1),  
                      3,
                      instr(
                            substr(v_string,1,instr(v_string, ':runner')-1),
                            ':',
                             1)-2)
                      )from x;
```